# Density of tuples of conjugate algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

One can see that algebraic numbers are dense in the complex plane by just looking at quadratic polynomials. I am interested in a "higher order" density of algebraic numbers.

More specifically: is it known that if $D_1,\ldots, D_n \subset \mathbb{C}$ are disjoint disks, then there is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ having at least one root in each $D_i$?

Comment: Just an idea: what about picking $n$ rationals $q_i$ wherever you like, then looking at $P(X)=\prod_i{(X-q_i)}+\epsilon$. Can't we find a small rational $\epsilon$ such that $P(X)$ is irreducible and its roots within some given $\delta$ of the $q_i$'s?

Comment: The irreducibility for most $\epsilon=1/n$, say, is given by Hilbert's irreducibility theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea by Yaakov Baruch works. Take any $q_i\in D_i\cap \mathbb Q[i]$ and take the polynomial 
$$
  g(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-q_i)(x-\overline q_i).
$$
It has rational coefficients.

If a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $2n$ differs coefficientwise sufficiently small from $g(x)$, then $f(x)$ has a root in each $D_i$ --- e.g., by Rouché's theorem. It remains to make $f(x)$ irreducible.

To perform this, one may use Eisenstein's criterion. Multiply $g(x)$ by a sufficiently large integer $N$ divisible by all the denominators of its coefficients. Then change its coefficients by 0 or 1 so that the leading one is odd, all others are even, and the last one is not divisible by 4. Finally, divide back by $N$.

Comment: That's nice. To make the question harder, say I am interested in algebraic integers instead of algebraic numbers. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Yes with algebraic integers:  Take g(x),N as above, then let f(x)=x^(1+deg g) + (2^M)*N *g(x) + 2, where M>>0 is a large integer.  Eisenstein's criterion gives irreducibility of f(x) and Rouche's theorem (applied to f(x)/(2^M *N)) gives that f(x) has (algebraic integer) zeros near zeros of g(x).